# how to get songs from sd card and store the songs in database

Tags: android

how to get songs from sd card and i have to store the songs in database and play the song. how to do that please assist me.  how to store the songs from sd card to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
String columns = {
    MediaColumns.TITLE,
    AudioColumns.DURATION,
    MediaColumns.DATA
    // add more columns if you want to fetch more data
};

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns, null, null, null);

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.TITLE));
    Long duration = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.DURATION));
    String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA));
    // handle song here
}
```

Comment: i use your code as follows i get IllegalStateException. my code:
final String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };

 cursor=managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
        
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
              values.put("bpm", 0); 
   values.put("songname", title); 
   db.insert("songs", null, values);
            // handle song here
        }

Comment: Where did you get IllegalStateException

Comment: i got it in String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.TITLE));